# Laravel Eloquent getting all categories children with Users and which users belongs to Roles

Tags: php, laravel

`Category` model and `Users` are `belongsToMany` which every user assigeed to a or multiple `Role`

each `Category` could be have multiple child and a child or nested children could be assign to a or multiple user,

i created this structure and work fine, my problem is how can i get user's roles in below query

without any getting roles which works perfect:

```php
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')->with('childrenCategories', 'users')->withCount('posts')->get();
```

adding additional query for getting user's role and not working correctly:

```php
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')
    ->with(['childrenCategories' => function ($child) {
        $child->with(['categories', 'users' => function ($user) {
            $user->with('roles');
        }]);
    }, 'users' => function ($user) {
        $user->with('roles');
    }])->withCount('posts')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can eager load nested relationships like this :

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')->with('childrenCategories','childrenCategories.users', 'users', 'users.roles')->withCount('posts')->get();
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

try this code instead:

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')
->with(['childrenCategories.categories',
'childrenCategories.users.roles','users.roles'])
->withCount('posts')->get();
```

Comment: thanks so much, your answer was very closed to correct query, mochakker :)